# How to stack units in a tile based game?

Tags: java, tiles

I'm trying to make it so that no more than 5 units can be stacked on a tile. I have a Tile class that creates each tile's preferences. Should I store the units in an array or arraylist in this class?

Answer (score 6):

Choosing a data structure will depend on what other features you want to support. In this case, you may as well use the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) since it's easier to work with and more flexible.

It would be best to just store a reference to the unit in the tile, and have the unit objects stored elsewhere.

Comment: Up to 5 units is so trivial though. Either will do.

Comment: I agree @Sidar. I say `ArrayList` because it's much easier for a new developer to handle. With easy functions like `add` and `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the nature of your question a Stack http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html be optimal, however it is last in first out so I don't know if that would fit your requirements, otherwise you could also use a queue. If order doesn't matter to you then use ArrayList, it is generally the most efficient (good comparison to linkedlist here http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/arraylist-vs-linkedlist/27017/view.html)